# Get the Server Access Information

Tags: c#

How can i get the information that the server is being connected to the network?

If it is connected then who will be get the access (getting the privileges of accessing the system)

Thanks,

Prasad

Comment: Why did you mark the answer on your previous question as accepted if you still need this?

Comment: Actually we are facing some network problems so i thought that my previous post is not coming so i thought of asking new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of information can be found with [WMI](http://linq2wmi.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For example take a look at this. This get's RAM and C drive information and also percents of processor working.

```
    DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    DriveInfo mainDrive = null;
    foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
    {
        if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name.ToLower().Equals("c:\\"))
        {
            mainDrive = drive;
            break;
        }
    }
    int totalRamSize = 0;
    int freeRamSize = 0;
    ManagementObjectSearcher ramSizeFinder = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_OperatingSystem");
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in ramSizeFinder.Get())
    {
        totalRamSize = Convert.ToInt32(obj["TotalVisibleMemorySize"]);
        freeRamSize = Convert.ToInt32(obj["FreePhysicalMemory"]);
    }
    //PerformanceCounter cpuUsage=new PerformanceCounter("Processor","% Processor Time", "_Total");
    int cpuUsage=0;
    ManagementObjectSearcher cpuPercentFinder = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_Processor");
    foreach (ManagementObject obj in cpuPercentFinder.Get())
    {
        cpuUsage = Convert.ToInt32(obj["LoadPercentage"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that information can be retreived using WMI (windows management instrumentation)